# Solr addfilterquery

Tags: mysql, search, solr

I want to perform a searchquery with Solr (in which I have almost zero experience). In MySQL in would be something like this:

```
$where .= "(r.xcoord BETWEEN '".$coordinaten["xcoord"]["begin"]."' AND '".$coordinaten["xcoord"]["eind"]."') AND (r.ycoord BETWEEN '".$coordinaten["ycoord"]["begin"]."' AND '".$coordinaten["ycoord"]["eind"]."')";
```

How can I achieve this in Solr?

Kind regards,

Pim

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours on google I found this post which helped me out :)

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

And this post on SO

[Solr between syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624155/solr-between-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
q=*:*&fq=xcoord:[xcoord_begin TO xcoord_end]&fq=ycoord:[ycoord_begin TO ycoord_end]
```